# Python: how do I add markers to lines in a figure at a particular y-value (y=1)?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot, scipy

I'm working on some code to produce a figure showing the evolution of the universe. [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u1QLC.png) is the plot I have. I would like it to have points on each line at the value scale factor a=1 (y=1). The code I have used is:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy as sp
from scipy.integrate import odeint

H = 71
Mpc = 3.085677581e+19
km = 1.0
Gyr= 3.1536e16
H0 = (H * Gyr * km / Mpc)

openlegend = ('$\Omega_{0}=0.99$','$\Omega_{0}=0.9$','$\Omega_{0}=0.7$', '$\Omega_{0}=0.5$','$\Omega_{0}=0.3$','$\Omega_{0}=0.1$')

t_0 = 0.0004
a_0 = 0.001

def Friedmann(a, t):
dadt = H0 * (((omega_m) * a**(-1)) + ((omega_r) * a**(-2)) + ((omega_lambda) * a**2) + (omega_k))**(1./2.)
return dadt

plt.rc('text', usetex=True)
plt.rc('font', family='serif')

omega_m = 0.5
omega_lambda = 0.49
t = np.linspace(t_0, 40, 200)
a = odeint(Friedmann, a_0, t)
plt.plot(t,a)

plt.legend(openlegend)
plt.xlabel("Time/Gyr")
plt.ylabel("Scale factor")
plt.grid(True)
plt.axis([0, 40, 0, 3])
plt.show()
```

In the above code I've removed the other 4 plot segments as this question was too code heavy but I think everything needed is in there. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: not clear what is your expectation in the graph. Do you want markers on line like :https://matplotlib.org/gallery/shapes_and_collections/marker_path.html#sphx-glr-gallery-shapes-and-collections-marker-path-py

Comment: find the x coordinate that leads to y=1 for each curve, then simply `plt.plot(x,1,'ro')` (or `'bx'`, or `'g+'` or whatever combination of color and style you prefer)

Comment: @triandicAnt no, I want to have one marker on each of the lines in the figure at the value where the scale factor is 1

Comment: @Julien I have kind of done this by just hovering over the points where the scale factor is 1 for each line, but is there a way getting the code to print the values of time when the scale factor is 1?

Answer (score 1):

First find the corresponding t value:

```
from scipy.optimize import fmin
def testfunc(t):
    return abs(1.0-odeint(Friedmann, a_0, t))

tmin=fmin(testfunc,t_0)
```

Then plot a marker at that place:

```
plt.plot(tmin,odeint(Friedmann,a_0,tmin),'ro')
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your second question, look at this:

```
a = np.sort(np.random.rand(100))*2
print(a)

[ 0.04076413  0.07112053  0.09023507  0.09191885  0.10870836  0.12426541
  0.15729747  0.16440316  0.20495337  0.22365309  0.24789116  0.24872571
  0.25064043  0.35076052  0.40280108  0.40847091  0.41375155  0.41872087
  0.42212211  0.43659979  0.44668006  0.45077655  0.481286    0.48560537
  0.52093186  0.52609924  0.56036436  0.56825814  0.62489957  0.62508836
  0.63732085  0.64103949  0.64947372  0.67048212  0.67637557  0.70392489
  0.70942404  0.72100452  0.75495165  0.7912313   0.79807935  0.80725338
  0.8267592   0.82791651  0.82841211  0.82848251  0.82904787  0.89153547
  0.92865278  0.96317979  0.99453125  1.00568198  1.00616394  1.01079887
  1.05477181  1.07749413  1.09642453  1.11116792  1.11821267  1.11954254
  1.11977944  1.1542566   1.17433921  1.19874957  1.25671437  1.27505726
  1.30764574  1.31788563  1.32370927  1.33032743  1.39506346  1.40655092
  1.40935935  1.42417487  1.45180301  1.47163972  1.57174153  1.59848992
  1.66061794  1.68826849  1.69218186  1.70790405  1.72978585  1.73469934
  1.78886879  1.82761629  1.83104592  1.83245659  1.83909942  1.84631466
  1.84894874  1.86030259  1.8784236   1.88678391  1.92236088  1.94622433
  1.96752263  1.98113385  1.99168009  1.99612737]

i = np.argmax(a>1) # first index giving a[i]>1
# BEWARE THIS WILL RETURN 0 IF NO VALUE IS GREATER THAN 1...
print(a[i])

1.0056819789665188
```

`t[i]` will then give you the corresponding time.
You can also use `i = np.argmin(abs(a-1))` to get the point closest to 1 rather than first above 1, but I guess the difference won't matter.